# Has any mainstream philosopher written extensively on the Eleusinian mysteries?

Tags: reference-request, greeks

Has any mainstream philosopher written extensively on the Eleusinian mysteries? So anyone with their own SEP page.

Also, I found a selection of texts (allegedly) referring to them, [here](http://www.roger-pearse.com/weblog/2014/10/02/primary-sources-for-the-eleusinian-mysteries/). While this isn't a long document, I would be interested in which selections were or are most highly valued.

Comment: Why would philosophers care about mystery religions? Isn't this a question more for history of religion or classics?

Comment: The obvious reference point is Hegel who refers to them throughout his work. Schelling discusses them in _The Philosophy of Revelation_ and Bloch has a section on them in _The Principle of Hope_. As far as I'm aware, none of those authors cite specific sources or documents, however...